# How to put checkmarks on a checklist in Google Docs

Tags: to-do-list, google-docs

**Note:** This question is specifically about Google Docs on Android, not Google spreadsheet on Android.

Instructions from this [page](https://www.controlaltachieve.com/2016/06/docs-checklists.html?m=1) shows how to insert a checklist using the Android app or Google Docs. I was able to follow those instructions on the Google Docs Android app, however, I need to then quickly and easily check off each item. The instructions on that webpage are given for a desktop web interface, because it refers to clicking the right mouse button and selecting an operation, but how do I do that within the Google Docs Android app? Is this impossible?

I currently believe the answer is "no", but I hope someone will prove me wrong about that.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, the checkmark bullet list is not available on Google Docs's Android version.
A not elegant workaround is to insert the checkmark character yourself then realign it.

Use one of the many keyboard apps that provide unicode characters (I used [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.mihainita.unicodecharmap)). Search for checkmark, copy and then paste it on your document. Then realign it to be on the same column than the real bullets as shown on the image.

**Disclaimer:** I am just a use of the linked app.

[image: IMG:]